# javac is able to find the file but not the java command

Tags: java

Example:
If there is a file HelloWorld.java in `c:\xyz\javaprograms\HelloWorld.java`

in the command prompt at the following default directory:

`c:\users\username>javac c:\xyz\javaprograms\HelloWorld.java`

it will compile and create a `c:\xyz\javaprograms\HelloWorld.class`

Now if I try to execute the program:
`c:\users\username>java c:\xyz\javaprograms\HelloWorld`

it says it did not find that file name.

if I go to the file path and execute the HelloWorld program (bytecode) then it runs fine

`c:\xyz\javaprograms> java HelloWorld`

Why did the java command not recognize the file with complete file path and why did it recognize the file only after going to the actual directory where the file is located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the class path with -cp :

```
 Java -cp MainFolderPath   mainclass
```

you can find the full documentation here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

Answer (score 4):

You don't pass a *filename* to the `java` command - you just pass a *classname*, and the classloader has to know how to load a class with that name.

It worked when you were in the right directory, because the current directory is implicitly on the classpath - but you don't *have* to do it that way:

```
c:\users\username>java -cp c:\xyz\javaprograms HelloWorld
```

should work fine too.

Answer (score 0):

@Start1
This happened to me some time back. Please add your java path to the windows `path` environment variable .

- go to desktop
- right click “my computer ” icon
- click on advanced tab
- click on environment variable button
- locate create path on User Environment or locate path on System Environment(careful here though)
- add your java bin path full path here. I System environment is used make sure you go till the end of the line , start with  a semi-colon used as separator here `;` then append your java path
- make sure your cp (classpath) is the actual one withouth .class extension to the class

I hope this helps